# Git: force a pull to overwrite local changes

Tags: git

I would like my local branch to be identical to the remote one. When I pull from the remote one, I'm getting conflicts, and in this case I would like not to resolve them and just get the latest version from the remote branch.

To hard pull I use in my local branch:

```
git reset -- hard

git pull
```

Nevertheless, when pulling I'm getting the error:

```
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Why? How can I pull the remote branch with overwriting? I thought of a workaround to just delete my local branch and create a new one and then pull, but is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+pull+overwrite+local+changes

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try doing a `git fetch` to bring the (local) remote tracking branch up to date with the remote version, then hard reset your local branch to that:

```
# from local
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/local
```

As to why you are still getting merge conflicts even after a hard reset, this could be explained by a few things.  The general explanation would be that your local branch has commits which are not present in the remote version.  In that case, Git cannot simply fast-forward your local branch, and must resort to doing a merge instead, which can lead to conflicts.

Comment: Thank you very much, while trying to understand, do you mean that from my local branch I should do "git reset --hard local" ?

Comment: I tried following your steps with "get reset --hard" in the end, and I'm still getting the same merging conflicts in the files

Comment: Are you sure you followed my _exact_ steps?  There should be zero conflicts appearing when doing a hard reset.

Comment: I'm doing "git fetch origin", then "git reset --hard", and then when pulling I get the merging conflicts

Comment: Not what my answer says, at all.  You need to hard reset _to the tracking branch for your local branch_.

Comment: Oh I see now, so in the last command I should type "git reset --hard origin/development" if my local branch is development? Thanks I'm still new to git

Comment: Yes, that's right, assuming your local branch is called `development`.